# Play framework inputDate form

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have specified a date variable in a model class:

```
@Required
public Date date;
```

And I populate this using the `@inputDate(journeyForm("date"), '_label -> "Date*")` in my form, it just displays like a dropdown calendar. When I display data entries the date displays like this `Thu Jan 03 00:00:00 GMT 2013`. My question is how do I also modify the time that is recorded in this form? I looked at the play framework api documentation for the html helper but there is no inputTime. Any advice is appreciated.

Ideally I would have a seperate variable for time.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `inputDate helper`, you build a `input type="date"` field. In some browsers, you have a dropdown helper (as in Chrome for example). The dropdown calendar gives you a `date` not a `datetime` object.

But your object `Date date` also holds time information. Since you only give it date information, the object will be constructed with empty time information. You will have to find another way to do it. You could use a jQuery plugin with timepicker functionnality. Here is one the [first results on Google](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/) when searching for jQuery Timepicker.

Answer (score 0):

For date/time:

```
@inputText(
    yourForm(fieldNAme),
    '_label -> "label",
    'type -> "datetime-local"
)
```

For time only:

```
@inputText(
    yourForm(fieldNAme),
    '_label -> "label",
    'type -> "time"
)
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Play 2.5. Use `@input(){}` to define a custom one instead.